# Отладка приложения которому требуются права суперпользователя.

Tags: linux, qtcreator, sudo

Нужно отладить в QtCreator программу которая создает UDP сокет, а для этого нужно права суперпользователя. Есть ли возможность сказать QtCreator чтобы он запускал программу с `sudo`, не запуская сам QtCreator из под `sudo`? Либо разрешить обычному пользователю создавать UDP сокет?

Comment: Возможно я не прав, но sudo вроде нужно только если номер порта ниже 1000

Comment: Может быть, но номер порта ниже 1000

Comment: отлаживай на порте выше 1024-го... по крайней мере слушай на нём сервером... если не хочется перенастраивать клиенты, то можно через iptables перенаправить порты...

Comment: вообще говоря, ЕМНИП, полноценные привилегии root'а не нужны... достаточно бинарнику какой-то мандат выдать `setcap`'ом (на вскидку сейчас не вспомню...)