# Создание RAW сокета

Tags: linux, c, сокет, qtcreator, sudo

Раннее я задавал вопрос [Отладка приложения которому требуются права-суперпользователя](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/813077/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F). Тогда было нужно создать сокет с привилегированным портом, это решилась заменой номера порта на не привилегированный.

Сейчас появилась похожая проблема. Нужно создать RAW-сокет для чего нужны права супер пользователя.

```
int main()
{
  int sockfd = ::socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP);

  if ( sockfd == -1 )
    printf("Error\n");
  else
    printf("Success\n");

   return 0;
}
```

Как мне уже подсказывали можно решить проблему с помощью `setcap`

```
$ ./Test 
Error
sudo setcap cap_net_raw+eip ./Test
$ ./Test 
Success
```

Но если запустить программу из QtCreator, то работать не будет. Пробовал применить `setcap` к QtCreator, но это не помогло.

Можно как то решить эту проблему?

Comment: Настройки запуска проекта подшаманить ? добавить кастмоную команду перед запуском?

Comment: У меня Qt Creator 3.5.1 и в настройках запуска только рабочая директория и аргументы. А кастомную команду какую? sudo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я сделал скрипт:

```
$ cat run_raw_sockets.sh 
#!/bin/bash

sudo setcap cap_net_raw+eip ./${1}
./$1
```

И добавил его запуск вместо запуска приложения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

QtCreator 4.5.0, и надеюсь я не открыл бэкдор к своей машине =)